# Trouble deciphering a deadlock in an innodb status log

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock, ado.net

We are accessing MySQL from the Microsoft ADO.NET connector.

Occasionally we are seeing the following deadlock in our innodb status and haven't been able to identify the cause of the problem. It looks like transaction (2) is waiting for and holding the same lock?

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
110606  5:35:09
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 45321452, ACTIVE 0 sec, OS thread id 3804 starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 1 row lock(s)
    MySQL thread id 84, query id 3265713 localhost 127.0.0.1 famdev Updating
    UPDATE people SET company_id = 1610, name = '<name>', password = '<hash>', temp_password = NULL, reset_password_hash = NULL, email = '<redacted>@yahoo.com', phone = NULL, mobile = '<phone>', iphone_device_id = 'android:<id>-<id>', iphone_device_time = '2011-06-06 05:35:09', last_checkin = '2011-06-06 05:24:42', location_lat = <lat>, location_long = -<lng>, gps_strength = 3296, picture_blob_id = 1190, authority = 1, active = 1, date_created = '2011-04-13 20:21:20', last_login = '2011-06-06 05:35:09', panic_mode = 0, battery_level = NULL, battery_state = NULL WHERE people_id = 3125
    *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
    RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 11144 n bits 152 index `PRIMARY` of table `family`.`people` trx id 0 45321452 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
    Record lock, heap no 12 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 25; compact format; info bits 0
    0: len 8; hex 8000000000000c35; asc        5;; 1: len 6; hex 000002b38ce6; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 00000002801f89; asc        ;; 3: len 8; hex 800000000000064a; asc        J;; 4: len 4; hex <data>; asc <name>;; 5: len 30; hex <data>; asc <data>;...(truncated); 6: SQL NULL; 7: SQL NULL; 8: len 16; hex <data>; asc <redacted>@yahoo.com;; 9: SQL NULL; 10: len 10; hex <data>; asc <phone>;; 11: len 30; hex <data>; asc android:<id>;...(truncated); 12: len 8; hex <data>; asc    J]  Z;; 13: len 8; hex <data>; asc    J]  Z;; 14: len 8; hex a39410acaa9b4340; asc       C@;; 15: len 8; hex <data>; asc     m S ;; 16: len 2; hex 8ce0; asc   ;; 17: len 8; hex 80000000000004a6; asc         ;; 18: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;; 19: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;; 20: len 8; hex <data>; asc    JR   ;; 21: len 8; hex <data>; asc    J]   ;; 22: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;; 23: SQL NULL; 24: SQL NULL;

    *** (2) TRANSACTION:
    TRANSACTION 0 45321448, ACTIVE 0 sec, OS thread id 3176 starting index read, thread declared inside InnoDB 500
    mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
    5 lock struct(s), heap size 1216, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
    MySQL thread id 85, query id 3265714 localhost 127.0.0.1 famdev Updating
    UPDATE people SET company_id = 1610, name = '<name>', password = '<hash>', temp_password = NULL, reset_password_hash = NULL, email = '<redacted>@yahoo.com', phone = NULL, mobile = '<phone>', iphone_device_id = 'android:<id>-<id>-<id>-<id>', iphone_device_time = '2011-06-06 05:24:42', last_checkin = '2011-06-06 05:35:07', location_lat = <lat>, location_long = -<lng>, gps_strength = 3296, picture_blob_id = 1190, authority = 1, active = 1, date_created = '2011-04-13 20:21:20', last_login = '2011-06-06 05:35:09', panic_mode = 0, battery_level = NULL, battery_state = NULL WHERE people_id = 3125
    *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
        RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 11144 n bits 152 index `PRIMARY` of table `family`.`people` trx id 0 45321448 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
        Record lock, heap no 12 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 25; compact format; info bits 0
        0: len 8; hex 8000000000000c35; asc        5;; 1: len 6; hex 000002b38ce6; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 00000002801f89; asc        ;; 3: len 8; hex 800000000000064a; asc        J;; 4: len 4; hex <data>; asc <name>;; 5: len 30; hex <data>; asc <data>;...(truncated); 6: SQL NULL; 7: SQL NULL; 8: len 16; hex <data>; asc <redacted>@yahoo.com;; 9: SQL NULL; 10: len 10; hex <data>; asc <phone>;; 11: len 30; hex <data>; asc android:<id>;...(truncated); 12: len 8; hex <data>; asc    J]  Z;; 13: len 8; hex <data>; asc    J]  Z;; 14: len 8; hex a39410acaa9b4340; asc       C@;; 15: len 8; hex <data>; asc     m S ;; 16: len 2; hex 8ce0; asc   ;; 17: len 8; hex 80000000000004a6; asc         ;; 18: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;; 19: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;; 20: len 8; hex <data>; asc    JR   ;; 21: len 8; hex <data>; asc    J]   ;; 22: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;; 23: SQL NULL; 24: SQL NULL;

        *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
        RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 11144 n bits 152 index `PRIMARY` of table `family`.`people` trx id 0 45321448 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
        Record lock, heap no 12 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 25; compact format; info bits 0
        0: len 8; hex 8000000000000c35; asc        5;; 1: len 6; hex 000002b38ce6; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 00000002801f89; asc        ;; 3: len 8; hex 800000000000064a; asc        J;; 4: len 4; hex <data>; asc <name>;; 5: len 30; hex <data>; asc <data>;...(truncated); 6: SQL NULL; 7: SQL NULL; 8: len 16; hex <data>; asc <redacted>@yahoo.com;; 9: SQL NULL; 10: len 10; hex <data>; asc <phone>;; 11: len 30; hex <data>; asc android:<id>;...(truncated); 12: len 8; hex <data>; asc    J]  Z;; 13: len 8; hex <data>; asc    J]  Z;; 14: len 8; hex a39410acaa9b4340; asc       C@;; 15: len 8; hex <data>; asc     m S ;; 16: len 2; hex 8ce0; asc   ;; 17: len 8; hex 80000000000004a6; asc         ;; 18: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;; 19: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;; 20: len 8; hex <data>; asc    JR   ;; 21: len 8; hex <data>; asc    J]   ;; 22: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;; 23: SQL NULL; 24: SQL NULL;

        *** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

We read [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-next-key-locking.html) on next key locking, but it doesn't seem to apply to us because we aren't doing selects for update.

**Update**

This morning I discovered a slightly different deadlock signature which might be the root cause for this deadlock. I have [posted that deadlock as a separate question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/will-these-two-queries-result-in-a-deadlock-if-executed-in-sequence) to keep things simple. I will update here if I can confirm that the other question is the cause.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more bandwidth and throughput.

Comment: I updated my answer with something about autocommit

Comment: BTW You get a +1 for this question because this type of question should keep DBAs on their toes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rolando](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/877/rolandomysqldba)'s answer was certainly helpful in getting us on the path to the right solution. However we didn't ultimately adjust our [autocommit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit) configuration, our isolation levels or the [innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog) configuration.

We believe the deadlock log we posted on this first question is a result of the deadlock we subsequently found and posted [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/will-these-two-queries-result-in-a-deadlock-if-executed-in-sequence). Since we resolved the issue with those two queries, we haven't seen any deadlocks since.

Comment: Although I could not find the solution, I was glad I could help !!!

Comment: Thank you for considering my suggestions and random MySQL babblings (+1) !!!

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA No problem ;) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I am seeing

I see three queries, all almost identical.

```
UPDATE people SET company_id = 1610, name = '<name>', password = '<hash>',
temp_password = NULL, reset_password_hash = NULL, email = '<redacted>@yahoo.com',
phone = NULL, mobile = '<phone>', iphone_device_id = 'android:<id>-<id>',
iphone_device_time = '2011-06-06 05:35:09', last_checkin = '2011-06-06 05:24:42',
location_lat = <lat>, location_long = -<lng>, gps_strength = 3296,
picture_blob_id = 1190,authority = 1, active = 1,
date_created = '2011-04-13 20:21:20',
last_login = '2011-06-06 05:35:09', panic_mode = 0, battery_level = NULL,
battery_state = NULL WHERE people_id = 3125;
```

The differences

TRANSACTION 1

iphone_device_time = '2011-06-06 05:24:42', last_checkin = '2011-06-06 05:35:07'

TRANSACTION 2

iphone_device_time = '2011-06-06 05:35:09', last_checkin = '2011-06-06 05:24:42'

Please notice that the column values are flipped. Normally, a deadlock occurs when two different transactions are accessing two locks from two tables with TX1 (Transaction 1) getting row A and then row B while TX2 is getting row B and then row A. In this case, it is TX1 and TX2 are accessing the same row but changing two different columns (iphone_device_time,last_checkin).

The values do not make any sense. At 5:24:42, your last checkin was 5:35:07. Ten minutes and 27 seconds later (5:35:07 - 05:24:42), the column values are reversed.

The big question is: Why is TX1 held up for almost 11 min ???

This is not really an answer. This is just bandwidth and throughout from me. I hope these observations help.

UPDATE 2011-06-06 09:57

[Please check out this link concerning innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog) : The reason I suggest reading this is something else I saw in your INNODB STATUS display. The phrase lock_mode X (exclusive lock) and lock_mode S (shared lock) indicates both locks being imposed (or attempting to impose) on the same row . There may be some internal serialization going on doing next row locking. The default is OFF. After reading this, you may need to consider enabling it.

UPDATE 2011-06-06 10:03

Another reason to examine this line of thought is the fact that all the transactions are traversing the PRIMARY key. Since the PRIMARY is a clustered index in InnoDB, the PRIMARY key and the row itself are together. Thus, traversing a row and and the PRIMARY KEY are one and the same. Therefore, any index lock on the PRIMARY KEY is a row level lock as well.

UPDATE 2011-06-06 19:21

**Check what [auocommit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit) value you have**. If autocommit is off, I can see two(2) possible problems

1. updating the same row twice in the same transaction
2. updating the same row in two different transactions

In fact, the SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS you show in the question has exactly both scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your input. We noticed that as well. I am confused why changes to two columns on the same row would result in a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks for your updates. I just checked our settings and autocommit is turned on (ie we haven't changed the default).

Comment: @RedBlueThing Please look over your transaction isolation level (variable is tx_isolation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tx_isolation). If you don't set this, the default is REPEATABLE-READ. it might possible that a different transaction isolation level may help with this unique situation.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that out and get back to you. Thanks again for your persistence :)

Comment: I discovered a different deadlock in our logs this morning which might shed some light on this problem. I have posted that as a separate question to keep things simple. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/will-these-two-queries-result-in-a-deadlock-if-executed-in-sequence