# Will these two queries result in a deadlock if executed in sequence?

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock, ado.net

This is almost certainly the cause of [my other question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/trouble-deciphering-a-deadlock-in-an-innodb-status-log), but I thought it was worth separating the two as I have a hypothesis based on the following log that I would love to have falsified or verified.

My hypothesis is that the [other deadlock](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/trouble-deciphering-a-deadlock-in-an-innodb-status-log) is actually a result of the following queries, with the original query hidden based on my understanding the innodb status only shows the most recent transactions (is this correct?).

Based on the log, I have checked our code and found the following two queries executed in sequence:

```
db.Execute("UPDATE people SET iphone_device_id=NULL WHERE iphone_device_id=@0 AND people_id<>@1", DeviceID, m_User.people_id);
// I have hard coded this query in this snippet to simplify things
db.Execute("UPDATE people SET company_id = 444, name = 'Dad', password = '<pass>', temp_password = NULL, reset_password_hash = NULL, email = '<redacted>@gmail.com', phone = NULL, mobile = NULL, iphone_device_id = 'iphone:<device_id_blah>', iphone_device_time = '2011-06-06 19:12:29', last_checkin = '2011-06-07 02:49:47', location_lat = <lat>, location_long = <lng>, gps_strength = 66, picture_blob_id = 1661, authority = 1, active = 1, date_created = '2011-03-20 19:18:34', last_login = '2011-06-07 11:15:01', panic_mode = 0, battery_level = 0.55, battery_state = 'unplugged' WHERE people_id = 666");
```

Where db.Execute is basically doing a *ExecuteNonQuery* on a System.Data [DbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.aspx) object.

So will this sequence of queries result in a deadlock? My hypothesis is that the two different field orders in the two queries causes the issue? Can I wrap the two queries up in a transaction to resolve the deadlock?

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
110607 11:15:01
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 45674214, ACTIVE 0 sec, OS thread id 2584 starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1216, 2 row lock(s)
    MySQL thread id 109, query id 4044915 localhost 127.0.0.1 famdev Searching rows for update
    UPDATE people SET iphone_device_id=NULL WHERE iphone_device_id='iphone:<device_id_blah>' AND people_id<>666
    *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
    RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 4611 n bits 152 index `PRIMARY` of table `family`.`people` trx id 0 45674214 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
    Record lock, heap no 7 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 25; compact format; info bits 0
    0: len 8; hex 8000000000000941; asc        A;; 1: len 6; hex 000002b8eedf; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 00000002801064; asc       d;; 3: len 8; hex 80000000000004c6; asc         ;; 4: len 3; hex 446164; asc Dad;; 5: len 30; hex <data0>; asc <data1>;...(truncated); 6: SQL NULL; 7: SQL NULL; 8: len 17; hex <data2>; asc <redacted>@gmail.com;; 9: SQL NULL; 10: SQL NULL; 11: len 30; hex <data3>; asc iphone:<data4>;...(truncated); 12: len 8; hex <data5>; asc    J]  };; 13: len 8; hex <data6>; asc    J]   ;; 14: len 8; hex <data7>; asc ~t  g C@;; 15: len 8; hex <data8>; asc G  I &S ;; 16: len 2; hex 8042; asc  B;; 17: len 8; hex <data9>; asc        };; 18: len 4; hex <data10>; asc     ;; 19: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;; 20: len 8; hex <data11>; asc    JL} Z;; 21: len 8; hex <data12>; asc    J]  M;; 22: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;; 23: len 8; hex <data13>; asc        ?;; 24: len 9; hex <data14>; asc unplugged;;

    *** (2) TRANSACTION:
    TRANSACTION 0 45674209, ACTIVE 0 sec, OS thread id 3804 starting index read, thread declared inside InnoDB 500
    mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
    5 lock struct(s), heap size 1216, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
    MySQL thread id 110, query id 4044916 localhost 127.0.0.1 famdev Updating
    UPDATE people SET company_id = 444, name = 'Dad', password = '<pass>', temp_password = NULL, reset_password_hash = NULL, email = '<redacted>@gmail.com', phone = NULL, mobile = NULL, iphone_device_id = 'iphone:<device_id_blah>', iphone_device_time = '2011-06-06 19:12:29', last_checkin = '2011-06-07 02:49:47', location_lat = <lat>, location_long = <lng>, gps_strength = 66, picture_blob_id = 1661, authority = 1, active = 1, date_created = '2011-03-20 19:18:34', last_login = '2011-06-07 11:15:01', panic_mode = 0, battery_level = 0.55, battery_state = 'unplugged' WHERE people_id = 666
    *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
        RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 4611 n bits 152 index `PRIMARY` of table `family`.`people` trx id 0 45674209 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
        Record lock, heap no 7 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 25; compact format; info bits 0
        0: len 8; hex 8000000000000941; asc        A;; 1: len 6; hex 000002b8eedf; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 00000002801064; asc       d;; 3: len 8; hex 80000000000004c6; asc         ;; 4: len 3; hex 446164; asc Dad;; 5: len 30; hex <data0>; asc <data1>;...(truncated); 6: SQL NULL; 7: SQL NULL; 8: len 17; hex <data2>; asc <redacted>@gmail.com;; 9: SQL NULL; 10: SQL NULL; 11: len 30; hex <data3>; asc iphone:<data4>;...(truncated); 12: len 8; hex <data5>; asc    J]  };; 13: len 8; hex <data6>; asc    J]   ;; 14: len 8; hex <data7>; asc ~t  g C@;; 15: len 8; hex <data8>; asc G  I &S ;; 16: len 2; hex 8042; asc  B;; 17: len 8; hex <data9>; asc        };; 18: len 4; hex <data10>; asc     ;; 19: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;; 20: len 8; hex <data11>; asc    JL} Z;; 21: len 8; hex <data12>; asc    J]  M;; 22: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;; 23: len 8; hex <data13>; asc        ?;; 24: len 9; hex <data14>; asc unplugged;;

        *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
        RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 4611 n bits 152 index `PRIMARY` of table `family`.`people` trx id 0 45674209 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
        Record lock, heap no 7 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 25; compact format; info bits 0
        0: len 8; hex 8000000000000941; asc        A;; 1: len 6; hex 000002b8eedf; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 00000002801064; asc       d;; 3: len 8; hex 80000000000004c6; asc         ;; 4: len 3; hex 446164; asc Dad;; 5: len 30; hex <data0>; asc <data1>;...(truncated); 6: SQL NULL; 7: SQL NULL; 8: len 17; hex <data2>; asc <redacted>@gmail.com;; 9: SQL NULL; 10: SQL NULL; 11: len 30; hex <data3>; asc iphone:<data4>;...(truncated); 12: len 8; hex <data5>; asc    J]  };; 13: len 8; hex <data6>; asc    J]   ;; 14: len 8; hex <data7>; asc ~t  g C@;; 15: len 8; hex <data8>; asc G  I &S ;; 16: len 2; hex 8042; asc  B;; 17: len 8; hex <data9>; asc        };; 18: len 4; hex <data10>; asc     ;; 19: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;; 20: len 8; hex <data11>; asc    JL} Z;; 21: len 8; hex <data12>; asc    J]  M;; 22: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;; 23: len 8; hex <data13>; asc        ?;; 24: len 9; hex <data14>; asc unplugged;;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out these two queries were at least part of the problem we were having. We have modified these two queries from:

```
db.Execute("UPDATE people SET iphone_device_id=NULL WHERE iphone_device_id=@0 AND people_id<>@1", DeviceID, m_User.people_id);
db.Execute("UPDATE people SET company_id = 444, name = 'Dad', password = '<pass>', temp_password = NULL, reset_password_hash = NULL, email = '<redacted>@gmail.com', phone = NULL, mobile = NULL, iphone_device_id = 'iphone:<device_id_blah>', iphone_device_time = '2011-06-06 19:12:29', last_checkin = '2011-06-07 02:49:47', location_lat = <lat>, location_long = <lng>, gps_strength = 66, picture_blob_id = 1661, authority = 1, active = 1, date_created = '2011-03-20 19:18:34', last_login = '2011-06-07 11:15:01', panic_mode = 0, battery_level = 0.55, battery_state = 'unplugged' WHERE people_id = 666");
```

to:

```
db.Execute("UPDATE people SET iphone_device_id=NULL WHERE iphone_device_id=@0 AND people_id<>@1", DeviceID, m_User.people_id);
db.Execute("UPDATE people SET iphone_device_id=@0, iphone_device_time=@1, last_login=@1 WHERE people_id=@2", DeviceID, System.DateTime.UtcNow, m_User.people_id);
```

So we are no longer updating the entire record (across multiple keys) and we are updating the fields in the same order. Since we made the change our deadlocks have disappeared.

Answer (score 7):

Even though the statements are executed in sequence, if they exist inside the same transaction, you must issue some kind of checkpoint between queries or tweek the [*transaction isolation level*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tx_isolation) before starting the transaction.

There are four values for tx_isolation:

- [READ-UNCOMMITTED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_read-uncommitted)
- [READ-COMMITTED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_read-committed)
- [REPEATABLE-READ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read) (default)
- [SERIALIZABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_serializable)

You could set the transaction isolation three(3) ways:

Write this in /etc/my.cnf and restart mysql

```
[mysqld]
autocommit=0
transaction-isolation = READ-UNCOMMITTED
```

or you could set it within the DB Connection itself before starting any new transaction:

```
db.Execute("SET tx_isolation = 'READ-UNCOMMITTED'");
db.Execute("SET autocommit = 0");
```

or disable autocommit using .NET protocols (Disclaimer: I'm not a .NET developer)

Although I am leaning toward READ-UNCOMMITTED to allow "dirty reads", you must experiment with other transaction isolation levels at some point to see which one has the desired effect.

Give it a Try !!!