# Similar function NOWAIT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

`Select for update nowait` doesn't work in MySQL 5x (innodb). Is there any function like NOWAIT in MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL provides the ability to set application-specific locking using the GET_LOCK() function. You can check if the mutex has been taken by using the IS_FREE_LOCK() function.

You can refer this thread for detail:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,45679,45679#msg-45679

Also, 
Non-blocking queries are not supported by MySQL:

http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/219041

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to InnoDB, `SELECT FOR UPDATE` has the potential for leaving lingering locks. This not a new subject as shown in the Forums:

- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,230883
- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,230883,231439#msg-231439
- http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=3597
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326424

I wrote about this before in the DBA StackExchange

- `Aug 08, 2011` : [Are InnoDB Deadlocks exclusive to INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/are-innodb-deadlocks-exclusive-to-insert-update-delete/4470#4470)
- `Jan 02, 2012` : [LOCK IN SHARE MODE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10010/lock-in-share-mode/10017#10017)
- `Mar 18, 2012` : [select for update gives error on indexed column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15208/select-for-update-gives-error-on-indexed-column/15219#15219)
- `May 09, 2012` : [Transaction Lock Timeouts When Updating a Row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17561/transaction-lock-timeouts-when-updating-a-row/17649#17649)
- `May 13, 2012` : [Cannot update certain rows in innodb tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17788/cannot-update-certain-rows-in-innodb-tables/17795#17795)

Note what the [MySQL Documentation said on this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html):

> When InnoDB performs a complete rollback of a transaction, all locks set by the transaction are released. However, if just a single SQL statement is rolled back as a result of an error, some of the locks set by the statement may be preserved. This happens because InnoDB stores row locks in a format such that it cannot know afterward which lock was set by which statement.

You best chance it to change [**innodb_lock_wait_timeout**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout) to your liking