# Is there any way to check whether a row is locked before updating it?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

The bottleneck of my app is concurrent updates to the same row in MySQL. Losing some updates wouldn't be nearly as bad as having them all to wait for each other to finish. Is there any way in MySQL to only update a row if there's no other concurrent update?

Comment: See if this helps: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22286/similar-function-nowait-in-mysql

Comment: Let's fix the problem a different way.  What is hanging onto the record so long that it matters?  That is, if we speed that up, you question becomes moot.

Comment: @James I'm not doing transactions, just updates, I don't think there are optimization opportunities inside an update statement, unless it could be affected by SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

Comment: @mustaccio I'll try that.