# How to select the rows affected by an update

Tags: mysql

When performing an `update` query (the following is just an example; any `update` query could be used) such as:

```
update t1 
inner join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
set t1.name="foo" where t2.name="bar";
Query OK, 324 rows affected (1.82 sec)
```

how do you see which rows have been affected (the `324 rows affected` in the response)? I tried converting the expression to a `select`, such as

```
select * from t1 
inner join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
where t1.name="foo";
```

but this also returns the rows that were already `name="foo"` before the `update`, too.
Conceptually, I would like to do something like

```
select * from rows_affected;
```

but of course this does not work. Is there a method that will allow the inspection/selection of rows affected by an `update` query? Or is the only solution to do the `select` *before* the `update` to see which rows *will be* affected?

Comment: Check out `RETURNING` in MariaDB.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a job for [SELECT FOR UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html). Please see MySQL Docs on this

I have discussed this over the years

- `Aug 08, 2011` : [Are InnoDB Deadlocks exclusive to INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/are-innodb-deadlocks-exclusive-to-insert-update-delete/4470#4470)
- `Jan 02, 2012` : [LOCK IN SHARE MODE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10010/lock-in-share-mode/10017#10017)
- `Mar 18, 2012` : [select for update gives error on indexed column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15208/select-for-update-gives-error-on-indexed-column/15219#15219)
- `May 09, 2012` : [Transaction Lock Timeouts When Updating a Row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17561/transaction-lock-timeouts-when-updating-a-row/17649#17649)
- `May 13, 2012` : [Cannot update certain rows in innodb tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17788/cannot-update-certain-rows-in-innodb-tables/17795#17795)
- `Aug 10, 2012` ; [Similar function NOWAIT in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22286/similar-function-nowait-in-mysql/22296#22296)
- `Feb 12, 2014` : [row locking within ACID transaction innodb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/row-locking-within-acid-transaction-innodb/58712#58712)

Answer (score 0):

Many rows can have t1.name="foo".

MySQL will **not update** that row, if it detects that you already have the value you try to enter

But only  the joined t1 rows that are linked to the condition t2.name="bar" will show up in the following query

```
select t1.id from t1 
inner join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
where t2.name="bar";
```

Of course it will **not detect** , if t1.name has already the value "foo" and so it would show t1.ids that **are not affected**.

If you need the actual row, without the not affted rows, you must write a stired procedure where you

1. SELECT the ids where already the t1.name is 'foo'
2. UPDATE your table
3. Do the above Query and remove all ids that are in 1.

As an Example

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (id int auto_increment primary key,name varchar(4));
> INSERT INTO t1(name) VALUES('foo'),('foo1'), ('foo'), ('test'), ('test'), ('test'), ('test'), ('test'), ('test'), ('test');
>  CREATE TABLE t2 (id int auto_increment primary key,name varchar(4));
> INSERT INTO t2(name) VALUES('bar'),('foo1'), ('bar'), ('bar'), ('bar'), ('test'), ('bar'), ('test'), ('test'), ('test');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROm t1;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name
> -: | :---
>  1 | foo 
>  2 | foo1
>  3 | foo 
>  4 | test
>  5 | test
>  6 | test
>  7 | test
>  8 | test
>  9 | test
> 10 | test
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM t2;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name
> -: | :---
>  1 | bar 
>  2 | foo1
>  3 | bar 
>  4 | bar 
>  5 | bar 
>  6 | test
>  7 | bar 
>  8 | test
>  9 | test
> 10 | test
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TEMPORARY table t1_temp SELECT id FROM t1 WHERE name = 'foo';
> ```

> ```
> update t1 
> inner join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
> set t1.name="foo" where t2.name="bar";
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name
> -: | :---
>  1 | foo 
>  2 | foo1
>  3 | foo 
>  4 | foo 
>  5 | foo 
>  6 | test
>  7 | foo 
>  8 | test
>  9 | test
> 10 | test
> ```

> ```
> select t1.id from t1 
> inner join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
> where t2.name="bar" AND t1.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t1_temp);
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  4 |
> |  5 |
> |  7 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8508657588d51b2d9e1234f458e9e9f4)*

Comment: I don't think that is true, from what I remember of MySQL it won't perform an update if the value already matches what the update statement is changing, So from the query, you are using it is possible it could return more than 324 records if some of those records already had a name of "foo". This also isn't counting for the possibility of more records being inserted between the update and select.

Comment: i added  more explanation, about your concern with the not updated rows. Your second concern is wrong, the question was  can we detect t1 rows , that are effected.

Comment: The question was about returning rows that where updated not about returning all rows that match a condition. That is why they asked about getting just the rows that where updated and not just a general select of rows that could have been updated..

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking for the [ROW_COUNT()](https://database.guide/mysql-row_count-explained/) function:

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT() as `affected_rows`;
```

It returns the number of rows affected by the previous query, so run it immediately after your `CREATE`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` to get the desired total.

Result:

```
+---------------+
| affected_rows |
+---------------+
|             3 |
+---------------+
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew, I'm interested in seeing the actual affected rows, not simply the count of affected rows.