# Stale table lock in AWS Aurora?

Tags: mysql, innodb, transaction, aws, aurora

We have an AWS Aurora (MySQL engine, r3.large) we are using to test a migration.

We have noticed a couple of queries that simply don't appear to run.  When I run

```
show engine innodb status;
```

it reports that there is a single table locked:

```
2017-06-21 18:20:49 2aea8928a700 Transaction:
TRANSACTION 6093969, ACTIVE 0 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
16 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 6164 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 12219, OS thread handle 0x2aea8928a700, query id 8842803 10.127.0.24 root updating
delete from <tablename> where id=<id>
Foreign key constraint fails for table `mydb`.`<otherTable>`:
```

This is a java application.  I have stopped the tomcat instances, and verified that there are no active connections, but the lock does not clear up.

I looked at a couple of tables in information_schema (INNODB_LOCKS, INNODB_LOCK_WAITS, and INNODB_TRX) but there are 0 records.

Is this an aurora problem?  Any solution other than AWS Support?

Answer (score 6):

I can't tell if this involves Aurora, but here is something worth noting: There are occasions when InnoDB will leave lock lying around. How does this happen ?

About six years ago, I answer this question : [Are InnoDB Deadlocks exclusive to INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/are-innodb-deadlocks-exclusive-to-insert-update-delete/4470#4470). In that post I mentioned the following from the MySQL Documentation:

> When InnoDB performs a complete rollback of a transaction, all locks set by the transaction are released. However, if just a single SQL statement is rolled back as a result of an error, some of the locks set by the statement may be preserved. This happens because InnoDB stores row locks in a format such that it cannot know afterward which lock was set by which statement.

This is still in the [MySQL 5.7 Docs on Deadlock Detection and Rollback
 (paragraph 3)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html)

You stated in the question

> I looked at a couple of tables in information_schema (INNODB_LOCKS, INNODB_LOCK_WAITS, and INNODB_TRX) but there are 0 records.

In [my answer to the 6-year-old question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/are-innodb-deadlocks-exclusive-to-insert-update-delete/4470#4470), I showed the query of this tabled used by a Percona Nagios Check plugin:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(IF(p.command = 'Sleep', p.time, 0)), 0) AS idle_in_trx
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCK_WAITS AS w
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX        AS b ON  b.trx_id = w.blocking_trx_id
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX        AS r ON  r.trx_id = w.requesting_trx_id
LEFT JOIN  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST       AS p ON  p.id     = b.trx_mysql_thread_id;
```

I tweaked that query to display the Process ID of the Blocking Transaction, the Process ID of the Requesting Transactions blocked and their respective values from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(IF(pb.command='Sleep',pb.time, 0)), 0) idle_in_trx,
pb.ID BLK_ID,pb.USER BLK_USER,pb.HOST BLK_HOST,pb.DB BLK_DB,
pb.COMMAND BLK_CMD,pb.TIME BLK_TIME,pb.STATE BLK_STATE,pb.INFO BLK_INFO,
pr.ID REQ_ID,pr.USER REQ_USER,pr.HOST REQ_HOST,pr.DB REQ_DB,
pr.COMMAND REQ_CMD,pr.TIME REQ_TIME,pr.STATE REQ_STATE,pr.INFO REQ_INFO,w.*
FROM       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCK_WAITS AS w
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX        AS b  ON b.trx_id = w.blocking_trx_id
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX        AS r  ON r.trx_id = w.requesting_trx_id
LEFT JOIN  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST       AS pb ON pb.id    = b.trx_mysql_thread_id
LEFT JOIN  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST       AS pr ON pr.id    = r.trx_mysql_thread_id
\G
```

If you run this, you will see one of two things:

1. The Process ID causing this log jam of locks
2. Everything coming up NULL (No transactions are blocked). This indicates that the lock is just stuck in LA-LA-LAND (Aurora is at fault). In that event, reboot RDS.

Comment: I did end up rebooting, and the locks went away.