# How do you read MySQL InnoDB Monitor output?

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock, insert, monitoring

I am new to DB Administration. I am trying to figure out the cause of deadlock exceptions, but I am unable to make sense of the logs.

The log says that "transaction 1 is rolled back". Why is this the case? The wager table has a foreign key relationship to the account table but is it "normal" for it (the trans running the insert) to not be able to obtain an S lock and therefore die as a result of a deadlock? I mean that seems pretty bad considering it is just a read to verify referential integrity.

And the second transaction is also writing to a wager table but there are no updates. So is the "mechanism" for creating auto-inc keys, or indexing mechanism or both that are causing a deadlock? Why would they not happen in serial fashion? Or may be they are but the wait period of some sort is too short.

Any help, pointers, further reading on how to use the log below to solve a deadlock problem appreciated.

```
111031 17:39:26
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 984899905, ACTIVE 180 sec, process no 10882, OS thread id 1104619856 inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 13 lock struct(s), heap size 3024, undo log entries 86
MySQL thread id 122, query id 28932942 localhost 127.0.0.1 bt update

INSERT INTO wager (amount_won, confirmation, created_by_partner, creation_date, description, fantasy_league, 
     first_game_start, image_thumb, image_wide, kind, last_game_start, last_update_version, locked, name, 
     num_future, num_past, num_present, partner, partner_wager_id, percent, progressive_num, result, status, 
     sub_kind, teaser_type, user_account, wager_amount, win_amount) 
 VALUES (null, 2, 1, '2011-10-31 17:39:26', 'Straight Bet', null, null, 'http://iphonebet_s.png', 
     'http://iphonebet_l.png', 9, null, 0, 1, 'NFL: KC +4, -140', 0, 0, 0, 26, '39812820-1', 
     null, null, 1, 1, null, null, 2176, '7000', '5000')

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 2712 n bits 264 index `PRIMARY` of table `bt/user_account` trx id 0 984899905 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 126 


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 984900638, ACTIVE 61 sec, process no 10882, OS thread id 1076607312 setting auto-inc lock
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
38 lock struct(s), heap size 6752, undo log entries 147
MySQL thread id 121, query id 28932947 localhost 127.0.0.1 bt update
INSERT INTO wager (amount_won, confirmation, created_by_partner, creation_date, description, fantasy_league, 
     first_game_start, image_thumb, image_wide, kind, last_game_start, last_update_version, locked, name, 
     num_future, num_past, num_present, partner, partner_wager_id, percent, progressive_num, result, status, 
     sub_kind, teaser_type, user_account, wager_amount, win_amount) 
 VALUES (null, 2, 1, '2011-10-31 17:39:26', 'Straight Bet', null, null, 'http://iphonebet_s.png', 
     'http://iphonebet_l.png', 9, null, 0, 1, 'NFL: SD/KC o +7.5', 0, 0, 0, 26, '39812916-1', 
     null, null, 1, 1, null, null, 2045, '260', '200')
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 2712 n bits 264 index `PRIMARY` of table `bt/user_account` trx id 0 984900638 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 72 
Record lock, heap no 107 
Record lock, heap no 126 
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
TABLE LOCK table `bt/wager` trx id 0 984900638 lock mode AUTO-INC waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Comment: Can you post the MySQL version?  How auto-inc locks work changed in MySQL 5.1+

Answer (score 2):

Please look at this phrase from your question

```
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED: 
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 2712 n bits 264 index `PRIMARY` of table `bt/user_account` trx id 0 984899905 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting 
Record lock, heap no 126
```

It says `index PRIMARY` has a shared lock (`lock mode S`) in Transaction 1

Now, check out this phrase from your question

```
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):     
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 2712 n bits 264 index `PRIMARY` of table `bt/user_account` trx id 0 984900638 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap     
Record lock, heap no 72       
Record lock, heap no 107       
Record lock, heap no 126
```

It says `index PRIMARY` has an exclusive lock (`lock mode X`) in Transaction 2. Three locks of this type are being held.

I have answered questions like this in the past, even as recent as 4 days ago

- [Trouble deciphering a deadlock in an innodb status log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/trouble-deciphering-a-deadlock-in-an-innodb-status-log/3185#3185) (Jun 6, 2011)
- [Will these two queries result in a deadlock if executed in sequence?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/will-these-two-queries-result-in-a-deadlock-if-executed-in-sequence/3224#3224) (Jun 8, 2011)
- [Reasons for occasionally slow queries?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3302/reasons-for-occasionally-slow-queries/3305#3305) (Jun 14, 2011)
- [Are InnoDB Deadlocks exclusive to INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/are-innodb-deadlocks-exclusive-to-insert-update-delete/4470#4470) (Aug 8, 2011)
- [Concurrently update with limit mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7363/concurrently-update-with-limit-mysql/7370#7370) (Oct 28, 2011)

*Here is the bottom line*: The PRIMARY KEY, contained in the clustered index (internally called [gen_clust_index](https://serverfault.com/questions/238845/what-is-gen-clust-index-used-for-in-mysql/239554#239554)), can experience intermittent locks when bulk inserting or performing multiple single INSERTs in a transaction. The application should be designed to perform a manual COMMIT after each INSERT. If this is not permissible due to the nature of the application, redesign the app to bulk insert into temp tables before populating the wager table.

As a sidenote, the reason these things do not run in serial fashion is due to the default transaction isolation as well as your app's design when it comes to INSERTs.

Here are the four(4) possible modes:

- [READ-UNCOMMITTED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_read-uncommitted)
- [READ-COMMITTED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_read-committed)
- [REPEATABLE-READ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read) (default)
- [SERIALIZABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_serializable)

There are probably deeper explanations that the things I have already stated. If there is anyone out there with any further explanation or information I've missed, please chime in.

Comment: Rolando thank you so much for you reply, I did read some of your other posts before making my own. It's just that it is not clear to me why inserting into table wager (or any table for that matter) would somehow be affected by a lock on primary in a different table user_account to which no insert   is being made.

Comment: In other words I do understand that there is an auto increment and if a bulk insert is too large it may lock up. But why would "it" mention that user_account is locking up when the insert and therefore auto inc is happening on wager table?

Comment: The auto_inc field resides in the gen_clust_index. It is locked and 'dirty read" values would probably have to exist for newly made rows not yet committed. Thus, one could foresee gap of auto_inc values. You may have to increase the size of ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1. Also, use a bigger bulk_insert_file_size. This could probably help.

Comment: Thank you once again Rolando. Indeed the deadlocks seem to be happening only during large bulk inserts. I looked up innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend and it seems that the more advanced is innodb_data_file_path = /ibdata/ibdata1:2000M;/dr2/ibdata/ibdata2:2000M:autoextend that mysql people suggest. I'm assuming here that by specifying larger numbers for ibdata1 and 2 I would get increase in ib_logfile0 and 1. (??) Will also try a bigger bulk_insert_file_size. Also it seems that increasing innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50 could be related.

Comment: You may want to strip down the innodb_data_file_path back to its default (ibdata1:10M:autoextend ) and use innodb_file_per_table. I explained it a year ago in StackOverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)

Comment: I went back to your first reply Rolando, and I wanted to make sure I understand your app. level suggestion. You were talking about single inserts and autocommit settings if I understand correctly. I did select @@autocommit and it is '1'. My application has hibernate and I don't think it is specifying and autocommit policy. I can play with it and set it to false or true. But if I understand correctly, I need autocommit=true. What I am not sure of is whether you're suggesting I need to break up my bulk insert into several separate inserts each in its own transaction.

Comment: Update : couldn't find bulk_insert_file_size. There is bulk_insert_buffer_size. But it's applicable to MyISAM only.

Comment: Sorry, bulk_insert_file_size is a big typo. I did mean bulk_insert_buffer_size.

Comment: Hey, did my answer ever help you ??? What it useful ???