# mysqldump --single-transaction, yet update queries are waiting for the backup

Tags: mysql, innodb, backup, mysql-5.6, mysqldump

If I use mysqldump --single-transaction, according to the docs it should do flush tables with read lock to get a consistent state and then start a transaction and no writers should be waiting.

However, I have caught the following situation last night:

excerpt from show full processlist:

hundreds of those...

```
   Command: Query
   Time: 291
   State: Waiting for table flush
   Info: insert into db_external_notification.....
```

then this:

```
Command: Query
Time: 1204
State: Sending data
Info: SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `db_external_notification`
```

and the rest of the threads are in Sleep

does anyone have any idea what are these inserts waiting for? I don't see any FLUSH tables or DDL or anything mentioned in the manual that can cause the queries to wait.

full mysqldump command

```
mysqldump --quick --add-drop-table --single-transaction --master-data=2 -uxx -pxx dbname
```

I guess --quick is redundant here, probably a leftover from earlier times, this script is very old, but shouldn't hurt anyting

Comment: full output of show full processlist and show innodb status (anonymized) is here: http://pastebin.com/D7WS3QAE

Comment: What is your full command line for `mysqldump`?  In particular, are you using `--flush-logs` or `--master-data`...? There are potential interactions among the options.

Comment: added full mysqldump command, thanks for looking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [**--single-transaction**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) option of [**mysqldump**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) does not do `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;`. It causes mysqldump to setup a repeatable read transaction for all tables being dumped.

From your question, you stated that the mysqldump's SELECT for the `db_external_notification` table is holding up hundreds of INSERT command to that same table. Why is this happening ?

The most likely thing a lock on the [gen_clust_index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-index-types.html) (better known as the Clustered Index). This paradigm causes data and index pages for a table to coexist. Those index pages are based on either the PRIMARY KEY or and auto-generated RowID index (in the event there is no PRIMARY KEY).

You should be able to spot this by running `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` and look for any page from the [gen_clust_index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-index-types.html) that has an exclusive lock. Doing INSERTs into a table with a Clustered Index requires an exclusive lock for handling the PRIMARY KEY's BTREE, as well the serialization of the auto_increment.

I have discussed this phenomenon before

- `Aug 08, 2011` : [Are InnoDB Deadlocks exclusive to INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/are-innodb-deadlocks-exclusive-to-insert-update-delete/4470#4470)
- `Dec 22, 2011` : [MySQL deadlock - cannot restart normally?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9592/mysql-deadlock-cannot-restart-normally/9613#9613)
- `Dec 13, 2012` : [MySQL InnoDB locks primary key on delete even in READ COMMITTED](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30382/mysql-innodb-locks-primary-key-on-delete-even-in-read-committed/30402#30402)

## UPDATE 2014-07-21 15:03 EDT

Please look at lines 614-617 of your PastBin

```
mysql tables in use 1, locked 0
MySQL thread id 6155315, OS thread handle 0x85f11b70, query id 367774810 localhost root Sending data
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `db_external_notification`
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 1252538405, sees < 1252538391
```

Note that line 617 says

```
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 1252538405, sees < 1252538391
```

What does this tell me? You have some PRIMARY KEY with an auto_increment on `id`.

Your max `id` for the table `db_external_notification` was less than `1252538391` when the mysqldump was launched. When you subtract `1252538391` from `1252538405`, this means that 14 or more INSERT commands have been attempted. Internally, this would need to move the auto_increment of this table at least 14 times. Yet, nothing can be committed or even pushed into the Log Buffer because of managing this `id` gap.

Now, look at the processlist from your PasteBin. Unless I miscounted, I saw 38 DB Connections doing an INSERT (19 Before the mysqldump process (process id `6155315`), 19 After). I am sure 14 or more of those connections are frozen because of managing the auto_increment gap.

Comment: I was looking for a long time and couldn't find any exclusive locks. i have pasted the full show innodb status at http://pastebin.com/D7WS3QAE, nothing there looks like exclusive lock on anything to me

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm wondering why don't they use a read-only transaction as it is clear that backup will never write, but I'm guessing that they are keeping that feature for their enterprise backup.

Answer (score 11):

The `--single-transaction` option of `mysqldump` **does** do a `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` prior to starting the backup job **but only** under certain conditions.  One of those conditions is when you also specify the `--master-data` option.

In the source code, from `mysql-5.6.19/client/mysqldump.c` at line 5797:

```
if ((opt_lock_all_tables || opt_master_data ||
     (opt_single_transaction && flush_logs)) &&
    do_flush_tables_read_lock(mysql))
  goto err;
```

To get a solid lock on the precise binlog coordinates prior to starting the repeatable-read transaction, the `--master-data` option triggers this lock to be obtained and then released once the binlog coordinates have been obtained.

In fact, `mysqldump` does a `FLUSH TABLES` followed by a `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` because doing both things allows the read lock to be obtained faster in cases where the initial flush takes some time.

...however...

As soon as it has obtained the binlog coordinates, `mysqldump` issues an `UNLOCK TABLES` statement, so there shouldn't be anything blocking as a result of the flush you started.  Neither should any threads be `Waiting for table flush` as a result of the transaction that `mysqldump` is holding.

When you see a thread in the `Waiting for table flush` state, that *should* mean that the `FLUSH TABLES [WITH READ LOCK]` statement was issued *and was still running* when the query started -- so the query has to wait for the table flush, before it can execute.  In the case of the processlist you've posted, `mysqldump` is reading from this same table, and the query has been running for a while, yet the blocking queries haven't been blocking for all that long.

This all suggests that something else has happened.

There's a long-standing issue [explained in Bug #44884](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44884) with the way `FLUSH TABLES` works, internally.  <strike>I would not be surprised if the issue still persists,</strike> I would be surprised if this issue is ever "fixed" because it is a very complex issue to resolve -- virtually impossible to truly fix in a high concurrency environment -- and any attempt at fixing it carries a significant risk of breaking something else, or creating new, different, and still undesirable, behavior.

It seems likely that this will be the explanation for what you're seeing.

Specifically:

- if you have a long-running query running against a table, and issue `FLUSH TABLES`, then the `FLUSH TABLES` will block until the long-running query completes.
- additionally, any queries that begin after the `FLUSH TABLES` is issued will block until the `FLUSH TABLES` is complete.
- additionally, if you kill the `FLUSH TABLES` query, the queries that are blocking will **still block** on the original long-running query, the one that was blocking the `FLUSH TABLES` query, because even though the killed `FLUSH TABLES` query didn't finish, that table (the one, or more, involved with the long-running query) is still in the process of being flushed, and that pending flush is going to happen as soon as the long-running query finishes -- but not before.

The likely conclusion here is that another process -- perhaps another mysqldump, or an ill-advised query, or a poorly-written monitoring process tried to flush a table.

That query was subsequently killed or timed out by an unknown mechanism, but its after-effects lingered until `mysqldump` finished reading from the table in question.

You can replicate this condition by trying to `FLUSH TABLES` while a long-running query is in process.  Then start another query, which will block.  Then kill the `FLUSH TABLES` query, which won't unblock the latest query.  Then kill the first query, or let it finish, and the final query will successfully run.

---

As an afterthought, this is unrelated:

```
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 1252538405, sees < 1252538391
```

That's normal, because `mysqldump --single-transaction` issues a `START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT`, which prevents it from dumping data that was changed while the dump was in progress.  Without that, the binlog coordinates obtained at the start would be meaningless, since the `--single-transaction` would not be what it claims to be.  This should not in any sense be related to the `Waiting for table flush` issue, as this transaction obviously holds no locks.

Comment: This answer is actually correct.

Answer (score 2):

I submitted a feature request: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?id=27103902.

I also wrote a patch against 5.6.37 that uses the same method as --single-transaction --master-data combination with --single-transaction --slave-data, which is provided as-is with no warranty.  Use at your own risk.

```
--- mysql-5.6.37/client/mysqldump.c.bak 2017-11-14 12:24:41.846647514 -0600
+++ mysql-5.6.37/client/mysqldump.c 2017-11-14 14:17:51.187050091 -0600
@@ -4900,10 +4900,10 @@
   return 0;
 }

+/*
 static int do_stop_slave_sql(MYSQL *mysql_con)
 {
   MYSQL_RES *slave;
-  /* We need to check if the slave sql is running in the first place */
   if (mysql_query_with_error_report(mysql_con, &slave, "SHOW SLAVE STATUS"))
     return(1);
   else
@@ -4911,23 +4911,21 @@
     MYSQL_ROW row= mysql_fetch_row(slave);
     if (row && row[11])
     {
-      /* if SLAVE SQL is not running, we don't stop it */
       if (!strcmp(row[11],"No"))
       {
         mysql_free_result(slave);
-        /* Silently assume that they don't have the slave running */
         return(0);
       }
     }
   }
   mysql_free_result(slave);

-  /* now, stop slave if running */
   if (mysql_query_with_error_report(mysql_con, 0, "STOP SLAVE SQL_THREAD"))
     return(1);

   return(0);
 }
+*/

 static int add_stop_slave(void)
 {
@@ -5841,10 +5839,12 @@
   if (!path)
     write_header(md_result_file, *argv);

+  /*
   if (opt_slave_data && do_stop_slave_sql(mysql))
     goto err;
+  */

-  if ((opt_lock_all_tables || opt_master_data ||
+  if ((opt_lock_all_tables || opt_master_data || opt_slave_data ||
        (opt_single_transaction && flush_logs)) &&
       do_flush_tables_read_lock(mysql))
     goto err;
@@ -5853,7 +5853,7 @@
     Flush logs before starting transaction since
     this causes implicit commit starting mysql-5.5.
   */
-  if (opt_lock_all_tables || opt_master_data ||
+  if (opt_lock_all_tables || opt_master_data || opt_slave_data ||
       (opt_single_transaction && flush_logs) ||
       opt_delete_master_logs)
   {
 static int add_stop_slave(void)
 {
@@ -5841,10 +5839,12 @@
   if (!path)
     write_header(md_result_file, *argv);

+  /*
   if (opt_slave_data && do_stop_slave_sql(mysql))
     goto err;
+  */

-  if ((opt_lock_all_tables || opt_master_data ||
+  if ((opt_lock_all_tables || opt_master_data || opt_slave_data ||
        (opt_single_transaction && flush_logs)) &&
       do_flush_tables_read_lock(mysql))
     goto err;
@@ -5853,7 +5853,7 @@
     Flush logs before starting transaction since
     this causes implicit commit starting mysql-5.5.
   */
-  if (opt_lock_all_tables || opt_master_data ||
+  if (opt_lock_all_tables || opt_master_data || opt_slave_data ||
       (opt_single_transaction && flush_logs) ||
       opt_delete_master_logs)
   {
```

I tested it with the following process with slaves to a very busy master using lots of InnoDB tables with FK relationships:

1. Stop slave A.
2. Wait ~15 minutes.
3. Dump DB 1 from slave B with option --single-transaction and --dump-slave=2
4. Start slave A until coordinates in dump from step 3.
5. Drop DB 1 and 2 from slave A.
6. Create empty DB 1 and 2 on slave A.
7. Load dump from step 3 into slave A.
8. Dump DB 2 from slave B with the same options.  DB 2 has FK relationships to DB 1.
9. Add replicate_ignore_db for DB 2 and skip_slave_start on slave A.
10. Restart slave A.
11. Start slave until coordinates from dump in step 8 on slave A.
12. Load dump from step 8 into slave A.
13. Remove replicate_ignore_db and skip_slave_start options from slave A.
14. Restart slave A.
15. Wait ~1 week.
16. Use pt-checksum to verify data integrity.

Oracle's patch submittal process is rather intensive hence why I went this route.  I may try with Percona and/or MariaDB to get it integrated.