# Does mysqldump use in memory pages during backup?

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysqldump

I mean when backup command is issued to database, does backup process read all data pages from disk or use in memory pages?

Comment: Interesting question - AFAIK, it chugs through the database table by table and outputs a text file. It's not even guaranteed to be consistent (i.e. do **not** do!) if you're making a hot backup! I doubt very much if it keeps  much in memory - why would it? How would it deal with a table bigger than RAM? If you want a hot backup, use Percona's XtraBackup!

Comment: @Vérace it's guaranteed consistent if you use InnoDB tables and `--single-transaction`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - maybe I haven't understood very well, but it appears that RolandoMySQLDBA is saying that if you attempt an insert into a table being dumped after the dump has started, then that insert will block until the dump (of that table) is complete - am I wrong?

Comment: @Vérace... link?

Comment: Sorry - you're in the thread - assumed you'd know - silly me! It's [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71961/mysqldump-single-transaction-yet-update-queries-are-waiting-for-the-backup#72526)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "in memory", I assume you are referring to cached data and index blocks.

`mysqldump` issues a bunch of `SELECTs`, which use the caching that is available to any other `SELECTs`.  Since it does not dump the indexes, most cached index blocks do not help the the dump process.

Xtrabackup has some extra hooks into InnoDB to help achieve a 'consistent' dump in a less intrusive way.  But still the caching is in effect.