# MySQL and AUTO_INCREMENT columns in multiple-column index for InnoDB tables: support status?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.1

Missing support for AUTO_INCREMENT columns in multiple-column index for InnoDB tables is a widely known limitation, as is the trigger workaround for when it is needed (see e.g [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120088/defining-composite-key-with-auto-increment-in-mysql)). Yesterday, however, I ran into [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416548/mysql-two-column-primary-key-with-auto-increment) claiming support for this feature was added as early as 5.1. I tried the following statement on my 5.7 install (mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64), and it appears to work flawlessly:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl1` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`data`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

My problem is that, for the life of me, I cannot find a positive statement of support of the feature on MySQL's documentation site - or elsewhere. I am rather wary of deploying in production something unannounced  (which might be experimentally present) so I hope somebody can point me to the official status of this.

**Edit:** It turns out that the manual contains, in parts unrelated, [this rather oblique statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-auto-increment.html):

*“…an InnoDB table with an AUTO_INCREMENT column requires at least one key where the auto-increment column is the only or leftmost column.”*

which suggests, but does not state, support.

**Edit 2:** Using information from @rolandoMYSQLDBA below, I also located [this additional snippet](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html): *"An AUTO_INCREMENT column must appear as the first column in an index on an InnoDB table."*. I am therefore accepting his answer.

And in case someone is wondering, the multiple column index thing is needed for table partitioning - the customer has auto_increment PK on all tables and they want to partition on a date column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, I would have closed this question as a duplicate. There are already close votes. In this particular instance, since you put a bounty on this question, I'll try to answer it as best as I can.

Look at the [first post you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120088/defining-composite-key-with-auto-increment-in-mysql). Note the table definition

```
CREATE  TABLE `issue_log` (
`sr_no` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `app_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `test_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `issue_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
primary key (app_id, test_id,sr_no)
);
```

The auto_increment column is `sr_no`. This is neither the only column nor the leftmost column in the primary key definition. Now, if the primary key was written

```
primary key (sr_no, app_id, test_id)
```

then `sr_no` would be leftmost. No error would have occurred with InnoDB.

When you ran the command

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl1` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`data`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

your auto_increment column `id` was leftmost.

You made [reference to a second post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416548/mysql-two-column-primary-key-with-auto-increment). Please note that in the answer to that second post, it clearly notes that MyISAM and BDB storage engines support auto_increment ids. When it comes to MyISAM, the auto_increment behavior allows an auto_increment number to be paired with one or more keys in such a way that the number 1 can appear multiple times but be associated uniquely with the columns. I have discussed this a few times over the years:

- `Apr 21, 2012` : [How can you have two auto-incremental columns in one table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16847/how-can-you-have-two-auto-incremental-columns-in-one-table/16849#16849)
- `Jun 10, 2012` : [MySQL get next unique value without auto increment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19019/mysql-get-next-unique-value-without-auto-increment/19020#19020)
- `Feb 26, 2013` : [How to use 2 auto increment columns in MySQL phpmyadmin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/how-to-use-2-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql-phpmyadmin/35479#35479)
- `Aug 28, 2013` : [How to go about modeling the main object of relationship?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48855/how-to-go-about-modeling-the-main-object-of-relationship/48856#48856)

Keep in mind that while InnoDB support for an auto_increment column in a `PRIMARY KEY` exists, it does not have the same auto_increment behavior as MyISAM. MyISAM can bind with other columns to allow a number to exist multiple times, InnoDB does not do that. Once an auto_increment value is used, it is unique for the whole table.

The excerpt you found

> an InnoDB table with an AUTO_INCREMENT column requires at least one key where the auto-increment column is the only or leftmost column.

comes from a [page in the MySQL Documentation that has to do with how replication sees and handles auto_increment values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-auto-increment.html). This is a vital issue since the order data are written on a Master may get serialized in a different order on a Slave.

Just recently (back on `Jun 16, 2017`) I answered [Does it ever make sense to create an index with additional columns after the primary key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176469/does-it-ever-make-sense-to-create-an-index-with-additional-columns-after-the-pri/176481#176481), where I mentioned from the MySQL Documentation that when there is an auto_increment column in a partitioned table, it is mandatory that the column is included in the `PRIMARY KEY` along with the columns that define the sharding of the table rows.

To conclude, let me just say this: support for auto_increment columns in a `PRIMARY KEY` in InnoDB does not come with any fringe benefits or additional bell-and-whistles like it does with MyISAM. That's why the MySQL Documentation does not have a lot written about it.

Support for this was mentioned long ago. If you look in the [MySQL 5.1 Documentation on `InnoDB Restrictions`](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-restrictions.html), you see bulletpoint #15

> For an AUTO_INCREMENT column, you must always define an index for the table, and that index must contain just the AUTO_INCREMENT column. In MyISAM tables, the AUTO_INCREMENT column may be part of a multi-column index.

There is more extensive stuff in the MySQL 5.1 Documentation [AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html). It is also [available in the MySQL 5.5 Documentation](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html). Unfortunately, these are in the old Documentation format. This is probably why you can't find anything now. Just be assured that the support is there.

Answer (score 0):

[*Conversion to InnoDB*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#index_issues) covers the issue:

A way to simulate the MyISAM 'feature' might be something like: What you want is this, but it won't work because it is referencing the table twice:

```
  INSERT INTO foo
     (other, id, ...)
     VALUES
     (123, (SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM foo WHERE other = 123), ...);
```

Instead, you need some variant on this. (You may already have a BEGIN...COMMIT.)

```
  BEGIN;
  SELECT @id := IFNULL(MAX(id),0) + 1 FROM foo WHERE other = 123 FOR UPDATE;
  INSERT INTO foo
     (other, id, ...)
     VALUES
     (123, @id, ...);
  COMMIT;
```

Having a transaction is mandatory to prevent another thread from grabbing the same id.