# select for update gives error on indexed column

Tags: mysql, index, transaction, select

here is my code:

```
mysql_query("start transaction");
$q="select max(id) from test for update";
$r=mysql_query($q);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($r);
for ($k=0;$k<100000;$k++)
{
$q="insert into test values ($row[0]+$k)";
$r=mysql_query($q);
}
mysql_query("commit");
```

if i run code with 2 browser if id column is not indexed code run correctly-  second session wait until first session commit -.

but if id column is indexed i get this error "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given " on second browser - waiting session -.

when i use mysql_error() before mysql_fetch_array() i get this error "Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction". why?

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT FOR UPDATE` tends to do row level locking in a deep way we tend to take for granted: Locking the corresponding index entries as well.

SELECT queries can perform locks on the [gen_clust_index](https://serverfault.com/questions/238845/what-is-gen-clust-index-used-for-in-mysql/239554#239554), aka the Clustered Index.

Here are three DBA Stack Exchanges questions I agressively looked over with [@RedBlueThing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2043/redbluething), the person who asked these questions. @RedBlueThing found work arounds for his questions.

- [Reasons for occasionally slow queries?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3302/reasons-for-occasionally-slow-queries/3305#3305)
- [Trouble deciphering a deadlock in an innodb status log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/trouble-deciphering-a-deadlock-in-an-innodb-status-log/3185#3185)
- [Will these two queries result in a deadlock if executed in sequence?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/will-these-two-queries-result-in-a-deadlock-if-executed-in-sequence/3224#3224)

Just to keep your question in perspective, when you look over these answers (don't look too deeply, even I get dizzy looking at my own convoluted answers) it should be quickly apparent that SELECT queries can lock data at the index level.

[You also have special cases of SELECT where you can lock specific rows on demand](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).

Look at this issue from another angle, "Are InnoDB deadlock exceptions possibly going to be thrown by SELECT?" The answer to that can be Yes under a certain condition: [If just a single SQL statement is rolled back as a result of an error, some of the locks set by the statement may be preserved. This happens because InnoDB stores row locks in a format such that it cannot know afterward which lock was set by which statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html).

Comment: thank u. when i reduce for loop to 15000, i cant see any problem . what is problem with many insert like 100000 insert? see line 5 of code.