# INNODB real-time locks?

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking, locked-objects

How can I view real-time locks in innodb when `information_schema.innodb_locks` is not available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick way to see it is to run [`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-monitors.html)

You will see

- exclusive locks
- shared locks
- corresponding queries
- number of read IO thread in use
- number of write IO thread in use

Here are some sample questions I answered that uses the output of [`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-monitors.html)

- [Will these two queries result in a deadlock if executed in sequence?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/will-these-two-queries-result-in-a-deadlock-if-executed-in-sequence/3224#3224)
- [Trouble deciphering a deadlock in an innodb status log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/trouble-deciphering-a-deadlock-in-an-innodb-status-log/3185#3185)

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Please keep in mind that a single INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE is itself a transaction when `autocommit = 1` (which is the default.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to locks in the TRANSACTION sections.